# Rule of thumb for album creation: layout, colors, background

Tags: images, page-layout, layout

I wonder if there exist some rules of thumb to suggest good looking layout for albums. As some generally-accepted rules exist for photography (e.g. rule of thirds, etc.) to give a hint for a better result, maybe some good practices also exist to choose pictures' layout, background, overall color and composition, etc.

A "no general rule exists" may be a valid answer, but in case any rule exist, please report them, possibly with examples.

Note that, in my case, I'm focusing on the creation of a printed photo album, in which the page's main target must be the photo (I'm trying to avoid clip-arts, texts, etc).

Comment: There's alot of templates being sold for this purpose. Research these for ideas.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a rule of thumb.  How you design or layout something depends on your/the client's requirements/personal taste.  "Good looking" is highly subjective - what looks good to someone might not suit everyone.

A photo album could be laid out in many different ways, from full page borderless photos, to individual photos placed in a grid pattern and everything in between those two extremes.

It might help if you were to find some examples of photo albums online, or find some layout templates perhaps for ideas. Looking at other peoples' work for inspiration is better than any "rule".

Generally however, I like to keep layouts simple and uncluttered, I like to make use of white space - but that's not a rule, just my taste. Some people like minimalism, others don't.  I've even designed things that I don't love, but my clients adore.